# android emulator crashes going into fullscreen

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm using the android emulator on OSX Lion
It crashes going into fullscreen (Alt + Enter)

```
emulator-arm[48695] <Warning>: CGDisplayBaseAddress is obsolete and returning NULL for display 0x4272300
Bus error: 10
```

Anyone know why this could be? Anyone else have the same issue?

Comment: I do have the same issue on Mountain Lion, on my MacBook Pro w/Core i5 CPU.